# The specified 'Field' field may refer to more than one table that appears in the FROM clause in an SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```sql
Select U.Field 
from (
  SELECT Field 
  FROM PhonesTBL 
  Inner join HistoryTBL on PhonesTBL.Field=Field.PhoneID 
  group by Field 
  Order By Count(*) Desc
  Union All 
  Select Field 
  From HistoryTBL Inner Join UsersTBL on HistoryTBL.UserID = UsersTBL.UserID 
  Where UBirthday Between #date1# and #date2# 
  Group By Field 
  Order By Count(*) Desc) u 
Group by u.Field 
having Count(*) > 1
```

The following query returns me the exception in the title, i dont know what am i doing wrong because im using the same union all method on other tables and it works, please help me :)

Comment: Your query has several typos, and won't even run.  Please show the definitions for all tables.

Comment: Chage "Inner join HistoryTBL on PhonesTBL.Field=Field.PhoneID" to "Inner join HistoryTBL on PhonesTBL.Field=HistoryTBL.PhoneID" and see if that helps. Also remove order by from inner queries, since it doesn't have any impact in final result set.

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

- Qualify *all* column names in a query, especially when you have more than one table reference.
- Don't use `order by` in the subquery

The following may do what you want:

```
select U.Field 
from (select PhonesTBL.Field 
      from PhonesTBL inner join
           HistoryTBL
           on PhonesTBL.Field = Field.PhoneID 
      group by PhonesTBL.Field 
      union all 
      select UsersTBL.Field 
      from HistoryTBL Inner Join
           UsersTBL
           on HistoryTBL.UserID = UsersTBL.UserID 
      where UsersTBL.UBirthday Between #date1# and #date2# 
      group by UsersTBL.Field 
     ) as u 
group by u.Field 
having count(*) > 1;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a simpler query to accomplish what you want -- but you don't specify what that is.  You can ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, an explanation, and your attempt at a solution if you want to investigate alternatives to this query.